# index.php script will not run at webroot

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, permissions, apache2

I have recently migrated a WordPress blog over to a new ubuntu server running apache2. The 
path of the blog is physically at `/var/www/approot/public/home/blog/(wp-stuff here)` which is the same path as the old server.

NOTE this is NOT a WordPress issue. I can execute a simple PHP script that I've created in this folder; `phpinfo.php` which returns just fine. However, the `index.php` returns a 403 forbidden message.

Weirdly, I can log into the WordPress console just fine if I access it directly at `http://www.example.com/home/blog/wp-login.php` and then `http://www.example.com/home/blog/wp-admin/index.php`.

But I cannot reach `http://www.example.com/home/blog/index.php` -- I get 403.

Also, I can access the categories pages, and any links under the `../home/blog/wp-content` folders, but just not the main page.

I do have an .htaccess file which looks standard:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /home/blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /home/blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Also, permissions are set the same on all .php files in the `../home/blog/` folder

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

Does anyone have any ideas of why the `index.php` is forbidden?

Comment: Check Apache's error log. If decision to block is made by Apache it should have an entry there.

Comment: Thanks,theres a bunch of these:

Comment: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/approot/public/home/blog/.html

Comment: From what I make out of this message -- it is Apache configuration -- it is different to what you have had previously. Please ensure that `.htaccess` files are allowed (you may need to put `AllowOverride All` or similar in appropriate place). The best way in general is to compare to your previous server config.

Comment: hmm, i do have that directive in my httpd.conf

Comment: Well .. 1) try to regenerate .htaccess from within WordPress (should be somewhere with PermaLinks name on it). 2) Please provide part of your config file -- especially how this virtual host is defined 3) Enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check rewrite logs (it may have something)

Comment: ok found the issue, involved my passenger installation - had to add following to my httpd.conf: <Location /home/blog> PassengerEnabled off </Location>  thanks for the  help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same issue I had.

Did you see a list of directories and and files instead of normal WordPress pages at `http://www.example.com/home/blog/` and `http://www.example.com/home/blog/wp-admin`?

If yes, you'd need the following:
DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml
(or something similar)

in either your httpd.conf (will apply to all virtual hosts) and each virtual host (if you're using virtual host)